# how to implement Vista-Like Ajax Calendar to website with smarty template engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, calendar, smarty

hello people I have s problem with implementing [Vista-Like Ajax Calendar](http://dev.base86.com/app/pages/scripts/vista-like_ajax_calendar_version_2/) to my website.

To header.tpl add this lines:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="Includes/plugins/DatePicker/styles/vlaCal-v2.1.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="Includes/plugins/DatePicker/styles/vlaCal-v2.1-adobe_cs3.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Includes/plugins/DatePicker/jslib/mootools-1.2-core-compressed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Includes/plugins/DatePicker/jslib/vlaCal-v2.1-compressed.js"></script>
```

and this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                                      
    window.addEvent('domready', function() { 
        new vlaDatePicker('ptime', { style: 'adobe_cs3', offset: { y: 1 }, format: 'd.m.y', ieTransitionColor: '' }); 
    });  
</script>
```

Ajax calendar is not working in this format.
Next I edit code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
   {literal}                                                    
        window.addEvent('domready', function() { 
            new vlaDatePicker('ptime', { style: 'adobe_cs3', offset: { y: 1 }, format: 'd.m.y', ieTransitionColor: '' }); 
        }); 
   {/literal} 
</script>
```

Calendar is not working with {literal}{/literal}.

What I do wrong? Where is a problem??

Comment: Have you checked the browser console / error log for javascript errors yet?

Comment: I have 2 errors:
 
1. Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox' add.php?v=video:37 - Fancybox is working 
2. Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)} has no method 'element' mootools-1.2-core.js:1205 - this js file is for this plugin whose not working 

And 1 warning: 
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. 

What can I do with this problem??

Comment: I think there could be a problem with the mootools core file. I get an  error in the example on IE9 but it works on chrome and opera. You could try to use another/newer mootools version. download here: http://mootools.net/download

Comment: There is the problem. I changed mootols file and now is working without errors :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing your js code in the template files like this.

```
{literal}  
<script type="text/javascript">  

        window.addEvent('domready', function() { 
            new vlaDatePicker('ptime', { style: 'adobe_cs3', offset: { y: 1 }, format: 'd.m.y', ieTransitionColor: '' }); 
        }); 
</script>
{/literal}
```

However I recommend putting Javascript in js files and then including them rather than using the code in the template itself.